# How to speed up numpy look-ups and make it more memory friendly?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

I'm new to numpy, have googled a lot, but it is hard for me (at the moment) to speed my code more up. I optimized my code as much as I could using @profile and numba. But my code is still very slow for a large number of documents and it needs a lot of memory space. I'm pretty sure I'm not using numpy the right (fast) way. Because I want to learn, I hope some of you can help me improving my code.
My whole code you can find on:
[my code on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/oliver_p_hd/softwareprojectlinguisticfeatures/src)
The very slow part is the log-entropy-weight calculation in the file CreateMatrix.py (create_log_entropy_weight_matrix and __create_np_p_ij_matrix_forLEW)

The profiling result of the two methods you can view [here](https://bitbucket.org/oliver_p_hd/softwareprojectlinguisticfeatures/src/217d17592881355c8cc0158f824cd3bb0dad5d99/PythonFiles/FeatureExtractionFiles/results.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Here the two methods:

## @profile

```
@jit
def create_log_entropy_weight_matrix(self, np_freq_matrix_ordered):
    print(' * Create Log-Entropy-Weight-Matrix')
    np_p_ij_matrix = self.__create_np_p_ij_matrix_forLEW(np_freq_matrix_ordered)
    np_p_ij_matrix_sum = np_p_ij_matrix.sum(0)
    np_log_entropy_weight_matrix = np.zeros(np_freq_matrix_ordered.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    n_doc = int(np_freq_matrix_ordered.shape[0])
    row_len, col_len = np_freq_matrix_ordered.shape
    negative_value = False
    
    for col_i, np_p_ij_matrix_sum_i in enumerate(np_p_ij_matrix_sum):
        for row_i in range(row_len):
            local_weight_i = math.log(np_freq_matrix_ordered[row_i][col_i] + 1)
            if not np_p_ij_matrix[row_i][col_i]:
                np_log_entropy_weight_matrix[row_i][col_i] = local_weight_i
            else:                
                global_weight_i = 1 + (np_p_ij_matrix_sum_i / math.log(n_doc))
                np_log_entropy_weight_matrix[row_i][col_i] = local_weight_i * global_weight_i
    #        if np_log_entropy_weight_matrix[row_i][col_i] < 0:
    #            negative_value = True
    #print(' - - test negative_value:', negative_value)

    return(np_log_entropy_weight_matrix)

#@profile
@jit
def __create_np_p_ij_matrix_forLEW(self, np_freq_matrix_ordered):
    np_freq_matrix_ordered_sum = np_freq_matrix_ordered.sum(0)
    np_p_ij_matrix = np.zeros(np_freq_matrix_ordered.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    row_len, col_len = np_freq_matrix_ordered.shape
    
    for col_i, ft_freq_sum_i in enumerate(np_freq_matrix_ordered_sum):
        for row_i in range(row_len):
            p_ij = division_lew(np_freq_matrix_ordered[row_i][col_i], ft_freq_sum_i)
            if p_ij:
                np_p_ij_matrix[row_i][col_i] = p_ij * math.log(p_ij)

    return(np_p_ij_matrix)
</code>
```

Hope someone can help me to improve my code :)

Comment: For a start I'd replace all `np_p_ij_matrix[row_i][col_i]` with `np_p_ij_matrix[row_i, col_i]`

Comment: Hi hpaulj, thank you. It is not much quicker, but it is a bit. Didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab a removing one level of iteration:

```
doc_log = math.log(n_doc)
local_weight = np.log(np_freq_matrix_ordered + 1)
for col_i, np_p_ij_matrix_sum_i in enumerate(np_p_ij_matrix_sum):
    local_weight_j = local_weight[:, col_i]
    ind = np_p_ij_matrix[:, col_i]>0
    local_weight_j[ind] *= 1 + np_p_ij_matrix_sum_i[ind] / doc_log
    np_log_entropy_weight_matrix[:, col_i] = local_weight_j
```

I haven't run any tests; I just read through your code and replaced things that were unnecessarily iterative.

Without fully understanding your code it looks like it is performing things that can be done on the whole array at one - *, +, log, etc.  The only `if` is avoiding `log(0)`.  I replaced one `if` with the `ind` masking.

The variable names are long and descriptive.  At some level that is good, but it often is easier to read code with shorter names.  It takes more concentration to distinguish `np_p_ij_matrix` from `np_p_ij_matrix_sum_i` than to distinguish `x` from `y`.

Notice I also replaced the `[][]` indexing with `[,]` style. Not necessarily faster, but easier to read.

But I haven't used `numba` enough to know where these changes improve its response.  `numba` lets you get by with an iterative style of coding that makes an old-time MATLAB coder blanch.

Comment: Hi hpaulj again :) Damn 'doc_log = math.log(n_doc)' is so obvious. Thank you again. I will test the rest. 'ind = np_p_ij_matrix[:, col_i]>0
    local_weight_j[ind]' look interesting, I never saw something like that. I will try it out.

Comment: Hi hpaulj, I tested both codes in combination with numba and my code is still about 20% faster. But your code is very informative.